# Geolocation not working in Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

I have the following script that gets your geolocation and redirects you
to Google Maps:

```
(function(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){location.href = 'http://www.google.gr/maps/place/' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;});
}());
```

The redirection works OK in Chrome for Windows and Firefox for Windows but doesn't work for Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android.

Why is this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The link was dead but that was not a problem. This question is old. Nowdays the geolocation api is supported by Chrome and Firefox for Android. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as you can see here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation

the geolocation API is not supported on all browsers and especially not on mobile browsers as of today.
I don't mean that it doesn't work but that it doesn't always work in the correct way: people would have to allow your webapp to access their position & to do it in a standard way.

Also, window.location seems to be better than location.href as stated in another answer.

Comment: It is the missing support of the Geolocation API for the mobile browsers that I tested. The window.location works the same with location.href - no problems.

Comment: Happy this was what you were looking for. Enjoy coding ;)